# Trying at add project_category taxonomy to Testimonials shortcode, to display a random testimonial of a certain project category

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

My PHP knowledge is limited. I'm trying to alter this code to create a shortcode [CSD-testimonial project_category="101"] to display a singular testimonial of the project category ID 101. No other attributes are needed besides the category.

NOTE: I'm using [CSD-testimonial], not [testimonial] to avoid conflict with the Divi builder's shortcode.

Thanks in advance.

```
function get_testimonial( $posts_per_page = 1, $orderby = 'none', $testimonial_id = null ) {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => (int) $posts_per_page,
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
    );
    if ( $testimonial_id )
        $args['post__in'] = array( $testimonial_id );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args  );

    $testimonials = '';
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $testimonial_data = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_testimonial', true );
            $client_name = ( empty( $testimonial_data['client_name'] ) ) ? '' : $testimonial_data['client_name'];
            $source = ( empty( $testimonial_data['source'] ) ) ? '' : ' - ' . $testimonial_data['source'];
            $link = ( empty( $testimonial_data['link'] ) ) ? '' : $testimonial_data['link'];
            $cite = ( $link ) ? '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" target="_blank">' . $client_name . $source . '</a>' : $client_name . $source;

            $testimonials .= '<aside class="testimonial">';
            $testimonials .= '<span class="quote">&ldquo;</span>';
            $testimonials .= '<div class="entry-content">';
            $testimonials .= '<p class="testimonial-text">' . get_the_content() . '<span></span></p>';
            $testimonials .= '<p class="testimonial-client-name"><cite>' . $cite . '</cite>';
            $testimonials .= '</div>';
            $testimonials .= '</aside>';

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    return $testimonials;
}

add_shortcode( 'CSD-testimonial', 'testimonial_shortcode' );
/**
 * Shortcode to display testimonials
 *
 * [CSD-testimonial posts_per_page="1" orderby="none" testimonial_id="" project_category=""]
 */
function testimonial_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => '1',
        'orderby' => '',
        'testimonial_id' => '',
        'project_category' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    return get_testimonial( $posts_per_page, $orderby, $testimonial_id, $project_category );
}
```

I have tried several different approaches based on tutorials and SO questions, but I lack the knowledge of how to register the project_category argument with the get_testimonial function, or of how to make this even sound like I sort of know what I'm talking about.